# Getting line feed escape characters in json data

Tags: java

Response I am getting from another service is the below logged json

```
jsonPromise = response.thenApplyAsync(responseJSON -> responseJSON.getBody(WSBodyReadables.instance.json()));
    JsonNode json = jsonPromise.toCompletableFuture().get();
    logger.info("log json" +json);
```

json data

```
{"Key":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nuMmrRTH53kDaTs2GiDes7RRTUmR5uvtiT9s7QeNBBWscft4JFFcp\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"}
```

When I am extracting the data using below code-

```
privateKey = json.get("Key").toString();
```

I am still getting the escape characters. Is there any other method which I got to use for extracting data from `JsonNode`.

Comment: I assume you are using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` as `javax.json` doesn't have a `JsonNode` type?

Comment: Yes.. I am not sure if this is better or not .. I just used the suggestions for import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toString`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toString()) gives a developer friendly string, but if you want the actual contents from a string node, you probably want [`textValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#textValue()).

> `public abstract String toString()`
>   Method that will produce developer-readable representation of the node; which **may or** may not be as valid JSON. If you want valid JSON output (or output formatted using one of other Jackson supported data formats) make sure to use `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectWriter` to serialize an instance, for example:
>
> `public String textValue()`
>   Method to use for accessing String values. Does **NOT** do any conversions for non-String value nodes; for non-String values (ones for which `isTextual()` returns false) null will be returned. For String values, null is never returned (but empty Strings may be)